# C#: Read XML Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

#### Using C#2.0 and VIsualStudio2005

I'm trying to access the "DisplayName" inside "MonitorResponseRecord"
from an XML file like the one Below:

```
    <Magellan xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd ..\Schema\Configuration.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
      <SchemaVersion>1.0</SchemaVersion>
          <MonitorScope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="CleanStationChemicalManifoldFeed5" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
            <PersonalSafety>
              <MonitorResponseRecord Enabled="true" DisplayName="ChemicalManifoldFeed5ControllerFault">
                <ExpressionMonitor>
                  <Expression>(ChemicalManifold.Feed5.DispenseValve = Open) and ((ChemicalManifold.Feed5.ViolatedRegion = HighProcess) or (ChemicalManifold.Feed5.ViolatedRegion = LowProcess) or (ChemicalManifold.Feed5.ViolatedRegion = Minimum))</Expression>
                  <TestInterval>0.1</TestInterval>
                  <MinimumTimeBetweenResponses>5</MinimumTimeBetweenResponses>
                </ExpressionMonitor>
                <Response>
                  <PostAlarm>
                    <AlarmName>ChemicalManifold_Feed5_ControllerFault</AlarmName>
                    <Parameter1 />
                    <Parameter2>Alarm Region = {ChemicalManifold.Feed5.ViolatedRegion}</Parameter2>
                    <Parameter3>{RecipeName}-{StepName}</Parameter3>
                    <Parameter4>FlowSetpoint = {ChemicalManifold.Feed5.Setpoint}-LPM, ActualFlow = {ChemicalManifold.Feed5.FlowMeter}-LPM</Parameter4>
                  </PostAlarm>
                  <ResponseEvent>
                    <TargetResource />
                    <Event>PA</Event>
                    <Reason>ChemicalSupply</Reason>
                  </ResponseEvent>
                </Response>
              </MonitorResponseRecord>
            </PersonalSafety>
            <PersonalSafety>
              <MonitorResponseRecord Enabled="true" DisplayName = "PressureValveFailure">
           ...
            ...                
             ...and soon
```

My current C# attempt is as follows, BUT it always hangs up when I try to `XmlDocument.Load("");`

```
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load("../UMC0009.Configuration.Root.xml");
                string attrVal = doc.SelectSingleNode("MonitorResponseRecord/@DisplayName").Value;
```

BUUUUT won't work :/ any help out there?

#### UPDATE:

the exception I recieve is as follows, and occures at the doc.Load("...") line:

`{"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."}  System.Exception {System.Xml.XPath.XPathException}`

Comment: If it "hangs up" on the Load then it doesn't like the path you're giving. Try the full path!

Comment: unfortunately made no difference :(

Comment: as @banging alludes: if you are "hanging" on the `Load(...)` then you should be receiving an exception. Give us the exception, please! :)

Comment: {"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."} System.Exception {System.Xml.XPath.XPathException}

Comment: Are you sure that exception is thrown by the Load()?! Because Load only throws XmlExceptions while the method that throws XPathException (what you have) is the SelectSingleNode() method!! Adolfo's answer seems to be what you need ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XPath query will be relative to the document root:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("MonitorResponseRecord/@DisplayName")
```

To make it search anywhere in the doc prefix it with double slash:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("//MonitorResponseRecord/@DisplayName")
```

If that still doesn't work I would try the above example after stripping out all those namespace declarations on the two root nodes.

Otherwise, with the namespace declarations you may find you need to define XML namespace mappings and use prefixes in your XPath like:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd");

doc.SelectSingleNode("//x:MonitorResponseRecord/@DisplayName")
```

Comment: this answer of yours gives me the exception:       {"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."} System.Exception {System.Xml.XPath.XPathException}

Comment: I've updated my third snippet slightly, shouldn't have had a prefix on the attribute.Did you try what I said about stripping the namespace declarations? Also what is the XML file size? Is it hanging because its too large?

Comment: @KrisG, when you use namespace prefixes in the XPath expression, you also need to supply an XmlNamespaceManager instance (which is what is pointed out by the exception in DarthSheldon's comment). See the example on the [`SelectSingleNode` doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx) to learn how to do that; you might want to update your third snippet accordingly. (Possibly, you'll need to add the prefix to the attribute again ... if I'm reading this correctly, `DisplayName` is an attribute in the default namespace, just like the `MonitorResponseRecord` element.)

Comment: Thanks O. R. Mapper, I've added the namespace mapping logic.

Comment: Thanks O.R. Mapper and KrisG I will try this out. @KrisG as far as the .xml file size it is 1.1Mb which is fairly large, is that possibly causing the hang-up? if so what can I do to combat this

Comment: it now gives following exception:  If I have the doc.Load(.../.../) line before your 3rd segment I get:   {"Could not find file D:\\OR\\B\\Xml\\CustomerSpecific\\UMC0009.Configuration.Root.xml'.":"D:\\OR\\B\\Xml\\CustomerSpecific\\UMC0009.Configuration.Root.xml"} System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}  OTHERWISE without that line I still recieve an exception on the .AddNamespace() line :{Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.} System.Exception {System.Xml.XPath.XPathException}

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("UMC0009.Configuration.Root.xml");

    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd");
    string attrVal = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:MonitorResponseRecord/@DisplayName", nsmgr).Value;
```

Using a namespace manager, specify your namespace URI and use it in your XPath.
It works for me.

Comment: I would do that but my program keeps getting hung up on the doc.Load() and jumps to exception, skipping everything else under it

Comment: @DarthSheldon: post the exception you are getting in your answer.

Comment: wrap your logic in a try/catch block and post the exception you get please

Comment: already in a try/catch block, the exception I receive is :      {"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."} System.Exception {System.Xml.XPath.XPathException}

Comment: Did you get that exception when executing my code in the answer? It should take care of that...

Comment: with your code the exception I get is: +  $exception {Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.:Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.} System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}

Comment: It says FileNotFound, you may need to change the file path to the one you had: "../UMC0009.Configuration.Root.xml"

Comment: still nothing, I'm even using                string fileName = "UMC0009.Configuration.Root.xml";
                string fullPath;
                fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);

Comment: Make sure the File Exists: `            string path = Path.GetFullPath("UMC0009.Configuration.Root.xml");
            if(!File.Exists(path)) Console.WriteLine("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12267/discussion-between-darthsheldon-and-adolfo-perez)